# OSX- is there an easy way to play mp4, avi, and wmv files?

Tags: macos, mp4, quicktime, avi, wmv

On Windows 7-8 Media Foundation allows playback of many types of video files.  Is there something similar on OSX 10.6 and above?  Is there an easy way to use Quicktime, for example?  I don't need to do anything fancy, just play the video with the ability to set the position, stop, and start.

Comment: not the right place for a question like this, but check out VLC Media Player

Comment: @ryanbwork It appears the OP is asking about playing video from code on OS X, not asking for recommendations about video player applications.

Comment: Exactly.  I'm not looking for video player applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Cocoa classes `QTMovie` and `QTMovieView`.  As I recall, you need a third party plug-in codec to play wmv files with QuickTime, but mp4 and avi should be OK out of the box.

Comment: Thanks- that's what I'm looking for, a way to write code that plays movies rather than a way to play them from the desktop.  There are lots of programs that play movies, I need to know what classes to use to incorporate that into a program.

Answer (score 0):

vlc player, MPlayer both are available for OSX. you can download both the player from respective sites for OSX.